# Best way to save data into db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have a little confusion in deciding which one of the following is the best practice in saving the data into db.

1.Performing all kinds of data manipulation operations inside code `(C#)` and inserting the result into multiple tables using separate `class` files and `procedures` which will save into individual tables. The `FK` relation is also be inserted from the code `(C#)`. In this case the result is cooked properly and fed to the procedures (separate for each table) which will save data for each table.

**OR**

2.Performing all kinds of data manipulation operations inside code `(C#)` and inserting the result into multiple tables using separate class files and `procedures` which will save into individual tables. In this case the result is cooked properly as in previous case and fed to the single `procedure` which save the data into multiple tables and which take care of the `FK` relation mapping.

**OR**

3.Passing the raw data to the `procedure` which will perform all kinds of data manipulation inside the `procedure` and after the data is ready, it will save the result to the tables.

**OR**

Is there any other approach better than the above if considering the performance?

I am a `asp.net` developer so I need the approach which best suit for `web applications`.

Thank You

Comment: In our environment we have multiple web servers and one database server. I would choose to make the webservers do the work than putting it all on the database server. My rookie answer is it depends on who you want to do more work, and your environment.

Comment: In my environment I have to tweak the existing application for better performance. So which would be the better approach? Or is there any other approach other than the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBA's answer: Go with option 3 because all business logic for CRUD belongs in the database.
App Developer answer: Use ORM classes to interact with the database so I can load balance and control that part too.
This is a never ending debate.
I have always used stored procedure to handle all the logic option, mainly because I like the fact that you can completely change the database and it won't matter as long as the signatures to the proc's input and output does not change. It also gives the DBA the ability to optimize the query in the proc and use parameterization etc etc. But I do understand that everything I have ever done could have been done the other way as well, it's a matter of what makes sense for what your database server is doing, and what the app is doing with the data, and what the data is .... nothing is black and white

Comment: In our application we have the 3rd option but it sometimes give `timeout` exception and sometimes `deadlocks`. So is this because of the large amount of process that happens inside the procedure? How to overcome this situation?

Comment: perhaps you are locking tables or have a transaction isolation level that is too high for what you are doing... \